# Undefined value with second JQuery POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a bootstrap modal with date selector (daterangepicker), after selecting some date jquery post is made and mysql query is checking free time slots for this date. then creates option list with free time slots and show it in modal. Until this everything works fine but when I choose one selection form option list and make another Jquery post to insert data in DB variable is undefined. I`m new in Jquery and spent half a day to search solution wit

1) My jquery POST

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#pkdateselect2').daterangepicker({
            "singleDatePicker": true,
            "startDate": "2018-02-01",
            "minDate" : "2018-02-01"
        }, 
        function(start, end, label) {
            $.post("ajax/pkaction.php", 
                {action: "checkdate", 
                 client_id: "<?php echo $id; ?>", 
                 userid: "<?php echo $userid; ?>", 
                 pkdateselect: start.format('YYYY-MM-DD')}, 
                function(data){
                    $('#pkdateselect2').html(data.wybranadata);    
                    $('#wyborgodzin').removeClass('invisible');
                    $('#pksave').removeClass('invisible');
                    $('#godziny').html(data.godziny);
                },
                "json"
            );    
        });    
    });
```

2) After that I got two fields in modal

First

```
<input type="text" id="pkdateselect2" class="form-control" name="pkdateselect2">
```

Second

```
<select class="form-control" id="godziny" name="godziny">
<option value="08:00:00">08:00</option>
<option value="08:15:00">08:15</option>
</select>
```

And button

```
<button type="submit" id="pksave" class="btn btn-primary invisible">Zapisz</button>
```

Until now everything works fine!

And after that I got second Jquery to POST again choosen date (pkdateselect2) and choosen time slot (godziny) When button (pksave) is clicked

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#pksave').click(function(){
        console.log('value ' + $("godziny").val());
        $.post("ajax/pkaction.php", 
            {action: "pksave", 
             client_id: "<?php echo $id; ?>", 
             userid: "<?php echo $userid; ?>", 
             pkdateselect2: $("#pkdateselect2").val(), 
             godziny: $("godziny").val()  }, 
            function(data){
                $('#pkmodalbody').html(data.results);
            }
            , "json"
        );
    });
});
```

Why are option value (godziny) and date value (pkdateselect2) empty when I`m receiving it in php?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get the value with wrong jquery selector

<s>$("godziny").val()</s>

should be

```
$("#godziny").val()
```

Comment: Don't waste time with answers related to typo stuff, please.  You can gain a lot of downvotes because of that.

Comment: To be honest that is my first Question, and such shame... Sorry for that. I will use better color formating in my editor.